# Rails : Order by attribute of a specific submodel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to order an array using an attribute from a specific submodel. Let's say I've got a list of Users, each users got Trades, I'd like to order my Users by ordering them by last created Trade.

I tried with

```
@invoices = User.includes(:payments).order('payments.last.created_at')
```

but it seems like last is considered itslef as an attribute rather than as a function, which raises this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
```

Is there a way to order my Users as planned ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the `last` method in this query if you want to order it in descending.

Intead use DESC inside order,

```
@invoices = User.includes(:payments).order('payments.created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to order it using a specific payment ? Let's say, if all of my users made at least 2 payments, I'd like to order my users by creation date of this specific 2nd payment, so that even if one of my users made 20 payments, only his 2nd will be used for ordering.

Comment: So you only want payments made after a specific date?

Comment: No. Let's say, you make 3 payments, in January, June and December. I make 3 payments, in January, September and November. If ordering ourselves by 2nd payment, you'd come first in list. by ordering by 3rd payment, I'd come first. All I need is a way to specify which submodel I want to use as ordering reference.

Comment: So, by second payment you mean payment done on June? A simple where clause can achive this. If that is not what you intended then it is probably a bit complex than a simple where clause